# Email updates based on it's value

Tags: batch

During email update batch, (10k+ batch size) it failed, and half emails got updated and half not. is there anyway i can resume process in terms of update emails which not got updated?

Here is code for batch:

```
    global class Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    private static final String EVENT_CATEGORY = 'Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate';

    public Boolean CommitChanges = false;
    public Boolean Success = false;
    public String EmailSuffix { get; set; }

    // Set of Account Ids to process
    private Set<Id> setAccIds = null;

    global Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate() {
        Init();
    }

    global Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate(Set<Id> accIds) {
        Init();   
        setAccIds = accIds;
    }

    private void Init() {
        setAccIds = new Set<Id>();
        Success = false;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return job_started();
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
        process_batch(scope);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        job_complete(bc);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator job_started() {
        Database.QueryLocator ql = null;

        try {
            if (null != setAccIds && false == setAccIds.isEmpty()) {
                ql = Database.getQueryLocator([
                    SELECT Id,PersonEmail,Secondary_Email1__c,Person_Account_Email__c,Reply_Email__c FROM Account
                    WHERE Id IN :setAccIds
                ]);
            }
            else {
                ql = Database.getQueryLocator([
                    SELECT Id,PersonEmail,Secondary_Email1__c,Person_Account_Email__c,Reply_Email__c FROM Account
                ]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        return ql;
    }

    global void process_batch(List<sObject> scope) {
        List<Account> accs = (List<Account>)scope;
        List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        try {
            if(null != accs && false == accs.isEmpty()){
                System.debug('*****' + EVENT_CATEGORY + '.process_batch. accs to process: ' + accs.size());

                for (Account a : accs) {
                    a.PersonEmail = null != a.PersonEmail && String.isNotBlank(a.PersonEmail)  ? a.PersonEmail + EmailSuffix : '';
                    a.Secondary_Email1__c = null != a.Secondary_Email1__c && String.isNotBlank(a.Secondary_Email1__c)  ? a.Secondary_Email1__c + EmailSuffix : '';
                    a.Person_Account_Email__c = null != a.Person_Account_Email__c && String.isNotBlank(a.Person_Account_Email__c) ? a.Person_Account_Email__c + EmailSuffix : '';
                    a.Reply_Email__c = null != a.Reply_Email__c && String.isNotBlank(a.Reply_Email__c) ? a.Reply_Email__c + EmailSuffix : '';
                    accsToUpdate.add(a);
                }

                System.debug('***** ACCOUNTS TO UPDATE:\n' + JSON.serialize(accsToUpdate));

                if(null != accsToUpdate && false == accsToUpdate.isEmpty() && CommitChanges){

                    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(accsToUpdate, false);
                    Map<Id, List<String>> mapFailedToUpdate = new Map<Id, List<String>>();

                    // Iterate through results
                    for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) { if (false == sr.isSuccess()) { List<String> temp = new List<String>(); for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) { temp.add(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields [' + err.getFields() + ']');} mapFailedToUpdate.put(sr.getId(), temp); } }

                    System.debug('***** ERRORS:\n' + JSON.serializePretty(mapFailedToUpdate));
                }

                Success = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){ Success = false; System.debug('*****' + EVENT_CATEGORY + '.process_batch. Execution failed. ERROR: ' + e.getMessage()); }
    }

    global void job_complete(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        try{ 
            //Validates if Email Masking is completed
            if(Refresh_Automation.CompleteEmailMaskProcess(false, true))
                //Method to Active WF Rules 
                Refresh_Automation.DisableValidationRules(false);

            // Email the submitter that the Job is finished.  
            if(false == SendApexJobSummaryEmail(bc.getJobId()))
                System.debug('*****' + EVENT_CATEGORY + '.job_complete. There was an issue sending summary email.');

        } catch(Exception e){ System.debug('*****' + EVENT_CATEGORY + '.job_complete. Error sending summary email. ERROR: ' + e.getMessage());}  
    }

    private Boolean SendApexJobSummaryEmail(String apexJobId){
        String htmlBody = '';
        Boolean success = true;

        try {
            // Get ApexJob that represents the Batch job using the Id   
            AsyncApexJob job = [
                SELECT  Id, MethodName, JobItemsProcessed, ApexClass.Name, CompletedDate, CreatedBy.Email, CreatedDate, NumberOfErrors, JobType, Status, ExtendedStatus, TotalJobItems 
                  FROM  AsyncApexJob
                 WHERE  Id = :apexJobId
            ];  

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toEmailAddresses = new String[] { job.CreatedBy.Email };  

            email.setSubject('Batch Job for ' + job.ApexClass.Name + ' - ' + job.Status);
            email.setToAddresses(toEmailAddresses);

            htmlBody = '<table><th><td></td><td></td></th>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Job ID:</strong></td><td> ' + job.Id + '</a></td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Created:</strong></td><td> ' + job.CreatedDate + '</td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Total Batches:</strong></td><td> ' + job.TotalJobItems + '</td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Batches Processed:</strong></td><td> ' + job.JobItemsProcessed + '</td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Failures:</strong></td><td> ' + job.NumberOfErrors + '</td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '<tr><td><strong>Apex Method Name:</strong></td><td> ' + (null != job.MethodName ? job.MethodName : '') + '</td></tr>';
            htmlBody += '</table>';

            email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);  
            email.setEmailPriority('High');    

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            success = false;
            System.debug('*****ERROR: Error sending Apex Job Summary email.' + e.getMessage());
        }
       return success;
    }
}
```

> 

```
global class Refresh_Automation implements SandboxPostCopy{

/* Method name  : runApexClass
 * Description  : Execute the SandboxContext for the Refresh process 
 * Return Type  : void
 * Parameter    : SandboxContext
 */        
global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context){
    System.debug(context.organizationId());
    System.debug(context.sandboxId());
    System.debug(context.sandboxName());
    String contextName = context.sandboxName();    

    run(contextName);
}

public static Organization currOrg = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization Limit 1];


/* Method name  : run
 * Description  : Execute the main logic for the Refresh process
 * Return Type  : void
 * Parameter    : String
 */
global static void run(String sandboxName){

    DisableValidationRules (true);
    UpdateUsersController.run(sandboxName);
    EndpointUpdateHandler(sandboxName,currOrg);
    MaskEmailsHandlerLead(sandboxName, currOrg);
    MaskEmailsHandlerAcc(sandboxName, currOrg);
}



/* Method name  : MaskEmailsHandlerLead
 * Description  : This method masks Inquiry email values in lower environments.
 * Return Type  : void
 * Parameter    : String, Organization
 */      
public static void MaskEmailsHandlerLead(String sandboxName, Organization cOrg){

    System.debug('Is Sandbox?: ' + cOrg.isSandbox);
    String EmailSuffix = '.'+sandboxName;
    System.debug('Sandbox name: '+ EmailSuffix);

    try{
        System.debug('Execute Batch_LeadEmailsUpdate');
        Batch_LeadEmailsUpdate batch =  new Batch_LeadEmailsUpdate(); 
        batch.CommitChanges = true; 
        batch.EmailSuffix = EmailSuffix; 
        Database.executeBatch(batch);

        if(Test.isRunningTest())
            Throw new EException();

    }catch(system.exception e){
        EException.createExceptionWithoutFuture('Error in Refresh_Automation.MaskEmailsHandlerLead Method', e.getTypeName(), EException.constructExceptionMessageString(e));
    }

}

/* Method name  : MaskEmailsHandlerAcc
 * Description  : This method masks Accounts email values in lower environments.
 * Return Type  : void
 * Parameter    : String, Organization
 */ 
public static void MaskEmailsHandlerAcc(string sandboxName, Organization cOrg){

    System.debug('Is Sandbox?: ' + cOrg.isSandbox);
    String EmailSuffix = '.'+sandboxName;
    System.debug('Sandbox name: '+ EmailSuffix);

    try{
        System.debug('Execute Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate');
        Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate batch =  new Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate(); 
        batch.CommitChanges = true;
        batch.EmailSuffix = EmailSuffix; 
        Database.executeBatch(batch);

        if(Test.isRunningTest())
            Throw new EException();

    }catch(system.exception e){
        EException.createExceptionWithoutFuture('Error in Refresh_Automation.MaskEmailsHandlerAcc Method', e.getTypeName(), EException.constructExceptionMessageString(e));
    }

}

/* Method name  : CompleteEmailMaskProcess
 * Description  : This method validates if Masking Process is Completed.
 * Return Type  : boolean
 * Parameter    : boolean, boolean
 */ 
public static boolean CompleteEmailMaskProcess(Boolean leadProc, Boolean accProc){

    Boolean completeProcess = false;
    Boolean leadVal = false;
    Boolean accVal = false;
    List<Refresh_Mask_Completed__c> refList = new List<Refresh_Mask_Completed__c>();

    try{
        Refresh_Mask_Completed__c refresh = [SELECT leadCompleted__c, accCompleted__c FROM Refresh_Mask_Completed__c LIMIT 1];

        if(leadProc){
            refresh.leadCompleted__c = true;
            refList.add(refresh);
        }else{
            refresh.accCompleted__c = true;
            refList.add(refresh);
        }

        if(!refList.isEmpty())
            Database.update(refList,false);

        refresh = [SELECT leadCompleted__c, accCompleted__c FROM Refresh_Mask_Completed__c LIMIT 1];
        leadVal = refresh.leadCompleted__c;
        accVal = refresh.accCompleted__c;

        System.debug('***refresh values: ' + refresh.leadCompleted__c + ' : ' + refresh.accCompleted__c);
        if(accVal == true && leadVal == true)
            completeProcess = true;

        System.debug('***completeProcess: ' + completeProcess);

        if(Test.isRunningTest())
            Throw new EException();

    }catch(system.exception e){
        EException.createExceptionWithoutFuture('Error in Refresh_Automation.CompleteEmailMaskProcess Method', e.getTypeName(), EException.constructExceptionMessageString(e));
    }

    return completeProcess;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the account Id values you'd like to use and then pass those in to the constructor:

```
Database.executeBatch(
  new Batch_AccountEmailsUpdate(
    new Map<Id, Account>([
      SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < 2019-03-20T00:00:00.000Z
    ]).keySet()
  )
);
```

You'll probably want to adjust the criteria for your query, but I'm not sure *how* exactly. You'll need to determine which records need to be updated.

Comment: can i use range in LastModifiedDate ? like Last modifieddate is last 3 days?

Comment: @SFDXTubeCube Yes, you can do that: `WHERE LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:3`. As I said, you'll want to figure out your own criteria for this.

Comment: @SFDXTubeCube What's your question?

Comment: sorry I post that here. I deleted that comment.